# I want to create unittest for send-mail(phpunit, mockery)

Tags: phpunit, phalcon, mockery

## Using

- phpunit(6.5.8)
- mockery(1.1.0)
- phalcon(7.2)
- phalcon/incubator(3.4.0)

## What I want to accomplish

I wanna create unit test for send mail.
This seems to be a simple test, but I couldn't do it.

Now, When I run the test, false is back.
But I expect true is back.

Am I making a mistake?

## Method I want to test

This is Methods to be tested

```
namespace \App\Controllers;

class TestController extends \Base\Controller

private function _sendConfirmationMail()
    {
        $to = "to";
        $from = 'test@example.com';
        $subjectText = 'subjectText';
        $subject = "subject";
        $headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"
                 . "From: Company <{$from}>" . "\r\n"
                 . "Bcc: test@example.com";

        $body = 'body ... ... ... ';

        if (mb_send_mail($to, $subjectText, $body, $headers, "-f {$from}")) {
        return true;
        }
        return false;
   }
```

## Unit test

This is unit test
(I expected true is back, but false is back now)

```
public function testsMailTransmissionSucceeds()
    {
        $mockTestController = $this->getMockBuilder(\App\Controllers\TestController::class)
        ->setMethods(array("_sendConfirmationMail"))
        ->getMock();


    // use reflection class because of private method
    $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($mockTestController);
    $method = $reflection->getMethod('_sendConfirmationMail');
    $method->setAccessible(true);
    $this->assertTrue($method->invokeArgs($mockTestController, "_sendConfirmationMail", array($clientData, $siteData, $params));
}
```

Comment: You are trying to mock the `Controller` method `mb_send_mail`. But the controller doesn't have that method. The `mb_send_mail()` is a build in PHP function. Don't know if Mockery can mock build in functions.

However, you can mock the `Controller` to see if the method `_sendConfirmationMail` was called offcourse. Also the ` $mockTestController` in your code is not a mock.. Please read more about mocking and testing.

Comment: Ah, You are right.　I modified code. but even so, This test return false... why...?

Comment: You would need to use something like Swift Mail and use different sender for tests, then you can check even mail content or you would need to mock _sendConfirmationMail and just check that it was called. 
In context of unit test mb_send_mail doesn't make sense, it's hard coded dependency.

Comment: @NaokiOshiumi The current test is not really a valuable one (if it was working). You create a mock and then want to triggered the mocked method to check if that method was called.. That would always be true. The scenario what you want to check (if I'm guessing right) is when a public controller method is called with a certain constructed request (scenario) that then the mail function should be called.